# How to show spinner selection in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

i am having spinner with country name and below i am showing flags according to country spinner.here i want to show flag according to spinner selection and not all..how can i show that in gridView?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
public class FanciersFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private Spinner spFindCountry;
    private RecyclerView rvFanciers;
    private ArrayList<CountryDetail> countryDetailArray;
    private LinearLayout llContainer;
    private String countryCode;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fanciers, container, false);

        iitializeView();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void iitializeView() {

        spFindCountry = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp_country_find);
        rvFanciers = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_fanc_items);
        llContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll_fanciers_container);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity() , 3);
        rvFanciers.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvFanciers.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        getCounties();

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("FanciersResponse");
    }

    private void getCounties() {

        if(Utility.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {

            final Call<Countries> resp = Utility.getApiService().getContries();

            resp.enqueue(new Callback<Countries>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Countries> call, Response<Countries> response) {

                    if (response.code() == 200) {

                        Countries countries = (Countries) response.body();

                        if (countries != null)
                            if (countries.getStatus() != null)
                                if (countries.getStatus().equals("OK")) {

                                    countryDetailArray = (ArrayList<CountryDetail>) countries.getCountryDetails();
                                    if(countryDetailArray != null)
                                        populateCountrySpinner(countryDetailArray);
                                        pupulateFanciers();

                                } else {

                                    Utility.ShowSnackBar(countries.getStatusMessage() , llContainer);
                                }
                    } else {

                        Utility.ShowSnackBar("Network Error" , llContainer);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Countries> call, Throwable t) {

                    Utility.ShowSnackBar("No Response" , llContainer);

                }
            });

        }
        else {
            Utility.ShowSnackBar(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet), llContainer);

        }
    }

    private void pupulateFanciers() {

        Fanciers rcAdapter = new Fanciers(getActivity(), countryDetailArray , new Fanciers.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(CountryDetail item) {

                if(item != null){

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable(Constants.COUNTRY_DETAILS , item);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , CountryBaseFanciers.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE , b);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
        rvFanciers.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    }

    private void populateCountrySpinner(final ArrayList<CountryDetail> countryDetailList) {

        ArrayList<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(countryDetailList != null){


            for(CountryDetail countryDetail: countryDetailList ){

                countryList.add(countryDetail.getCountryName());
            }

        }
        /*adapterCountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.tv_country_name, countryList);
        spCountry.setAdapter(adapterCountry);*/

        HintSpinner<String> hintSpinner = new HintSpinner<>(
                spFindCountry,
                // Default layout - You don't need to pass in any layout id, just your hint text and
                // your list data
                new HintAdapter<>(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.find_country), countryList),
                new HintSpinner.Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(int position, String itemAtPosition) {
                        // Here you handle the on item selected event (this skips the hint selected event)

                        countryCode = countryDetailList.get(position).getCountryCode();



                    }
                });
        hintSpinner.init();
    }


}
```

I am getting all flags in gridview but i want on selection of spinner..kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GridView`, try extending an `ArrayAdapter` class to use images, setting it in a `ListView` and implementing a filter based on country name. This should be fine if you want only one flag to be displayed at a time.

Comment: its already working without selection...wht can be the other option

Comment: You wanted to display _one_ country flag according to selection in spinner right?